# Windows Live Mail: Sent folder remains empty

Tags: windows-10, email, windows-live-mail

We have moved to another hosting provider.
From that moment, it appears that the "sent" folder in Windows Live Mail remains empty.
When we check the "sent" folder in webmail, that folder is empty as well.
Same for the folders "drafts", "spam" and "trash".

Only the inbox appear to behave as it should.

We have created the same mail account in TB. That causes TB to hang on sending emails.

However, the sent emails are being received by the addressees.

If we create and send emails from webmail, the "sent" folder shows sent emails both on webmail and in the local email client.

I hope someone can push me in the right direction.

Comment: "created the same mail account in TB. That causes TB to hang on sending emails"   <-- Verify the mail sending ports and protocol carefully (ask the new mail ISP) and test until a Send / Receive completes normally.  Try with a different email app (Outlook for example).

Comment: Thanks John. ISP is not very helpful. I have got it working in WLM and TB by setting the root folder to "Inbox". Problem is: the emails that have been sent before we discovered the issue, are not in any "sent" folder. Would you know how to retrieve those emails?
BTW I have made this a new question as well.

Comment: Close Windows Live Mail and look in C:\Users\jusername\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Live Mail and see if there is an older file there.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to set the correct root folder path in the email client.
The lost emails that have been sent but were not stored in webmail, have been retrieved in the local email folders.
From those folders we have copied the messages to the correct folders in each email account.